# How can I get the total number of sites in a site collection?

Tags: 2007, administration

Is there any way to know the total number of sites in a site collection?
Any tool to how the tree of sites with total number of sites or something similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SPSite.AllWebs.Count
```

SPSite.AllWebs returns ALL sites (flattened) in a site collection, regardless of their level.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Webs Web Service and jQuery to get the enumeration of all of the subwebs using the GetAllSubWebCollection operation. The nice things about this approach:

- You can do it all client-side
- You can format the output however you'd like

Check out my [jQuery Library for SharePoint Web Services](http://spservices.codeplex.com) to make this easy.

Comment: I hadn't considered using it in this way.  Interesting idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use stsadm -o enumsubwebs but you way have to run this recursively.  In the past I've written some recursive functions using the api that grabs the info, but you need to be careful where you run that sort of script.

Comment: What I need is a tool or a script to give me the total in one shot if possible.

Answer (score 1):

[This free reporting tool](http://www.sharepointjoel.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=292) from Quest will give you a site count and fair bit more besides.

Comment: When I tried to download this toolset, the site asked me for a bunch of info and said I'd be contacted by a salesperson.  Certainly *not* my goal.  Maybe I missed something?

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, Marc. All I can say is that it worked fine for me - I wasn't asked for a bunch of info and I wasn't told I'd be contacted by a salesperson.